# Xamarin AdMob error

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android, admob

I try to connect with AdMob (Google Play Services Ads) Banner using Xamarin C# code, When I load:

adView.loadAd(adRequest);

Xamarin Show Error message ( System.NullReferenceException )

[Error message picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VGFwe.png)

The link of my code: https://github.com/hussien89aa/XamarinAndroidTutorial/blob/master/Admob.txt

I try to use different version of Emulators, SDKs and Google play services Ads versions (27.0 till 42.1002 Nougat) but still not work and show same error

My SDK library contain Google play Services and I use Visual Studio 2017

Comment: Can you make sure you have adView1 in the correct layout? It looks like `FindViewById` cant find the view

Comment: It's show on the main layout please check the photo https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B8NSSE7X0NQ5N2pXUHlVYzFwWWs

Comment: check the banner here https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B8NSSE7X0NQ5UldpV3h2bzMwb0E but not work

Comment: I cannot find any problem with your code, have you tested the [official demo](https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/monodroid/google-services/AdMobExample/)? Did you install the  `Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Ads` package?

Comment: I tried to install multiple versions of Google Play services Ads and I have latest version of Xamarin

Answer (score 0):

Change the compile preferences with Android 9.0 or more (API 28.0).
I've read somewhere it's a requirments with the latest version of AdMob, but can't find the source anymore.